# Xpath read given attribute tag value

Tags: java, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MS_xml_root>
<message>
<field id="A">A</field>
<field id="B">B</field>
<field id="C"></field>
</message>
<message>
<field id="A">A</field>
<field id="B">B</field>
<field id="C"></field>
</message>
</MS_xml_root>
```

I want to read the field tag value by giving the field id key using XPath. But I can read the attribute value.

```
String exp = "//MS_xml_root/message/field"
NodeList list = (NodeList) xPath.compile(exp).evaulate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
for(int i=0;i < list.getLength(); i++){
//need to read the value here.
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *field tag value*? You want the text content of the field tag?

Comment: I want to pass id key 'A' and get field tag value that is A

Comment: What does “But I can read the attribute value” mean?  Is that a question?  Are you letting us know that you are capable of reading attributes of XML elements?

Comment: No, it is not a question. Using element.getAttribute("id") can read the id value. But I asking when I pass id value 'A' to read the field tag value.

Comment: Try using `//MS_xml_root/message/field[@id='A']/text()` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

```java
String id = "A";
String exp = "//MS_xml_root/message/field[@id='" + id + "']";
```

will get the nodes with `id="A"`.  Use `NODE` instead of `NODESET` to get a single `Node`.

If you want the attribute value, use something like:

```java
String exp = "//MS_xml_root/message/field/@id";
```

Comment: but I want to pass id key A and get field tag value. This is my requirement.

Comment: Parameterize your exp.  I have updated the code above

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need the Java method to get the TextContent of nodes which have a specific ID.
You could do it with below code:

```
private static List<String> getFieldNodeValues(Document doc, String id) throws XPathExpressionException {
        
        String exp = "//MS_xml_root/message/field[@id=" + "\"" + id + "\"" + "]";
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList list = (NodeList) xpath.compile(exp).evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++ ) {
            Node node = list.item(i);
            res.add(node.getTextContent());
        }
        return res;
    }
```

You may want a list of values not one value, because your xml seems to have more than one field for a given ID value.

Comment: is it possible to pass a series of id as an input and return the result as a group?
eg: input A,B,C and response [A,B,C]

Comment: Yes you can just pass a list of strings instead of `String id` pass `List<String> ids` and for each `id` do the xpath query.